# MongoDB $addtoSet and $set in the same operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

In my Meteor/javascript app, I am trying to update a specific MongoDB document via `$addToSet` on a certain part of that document followed by `$set` on a different part of that same document. There is no overlap between these two portions, so from what I read online it should be safe. But I can't seem to get the syntax correct. How can I carry out these two operations in one javascript command? The below works as two separate commands, and I assume it would be faster if they could be combined into just one write to Mongo.

```
Collection.update(
  {_id: documentId},
  {$addToSet:
    {data:
      {$each: newData}
    }
  }
);
Collection.update(
  {_id: documentId},
  {$set:
    {lastTxn: lastTxn,
     updatedAt: new Date()}
  }
);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As long as they are not on the same path ( which is the one thing you cannot do ) then it is perfectly fine. The [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operations are just top level "keys" of the "update document":

```
 Collection.update(
  { "_id": documentId },
  {
    "$addToSet": { "data": { "$each": newData } },
    "$set": { 
       "lastTxn": lastTxn,
       "updatedAt": new Date()
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! And is it true that the single command in your answer is faster than the dual commands in my question?

Comment: @JonCursi One trip to the server is certainly faster, as is one operation in general. I makes sense to update multiple fields at the same time right? That's all that happens, just with different types of operations because MongoDB is a document store that supports that, and not a SQL table. In fact think of it like a "transaction" updating the parent and related document in one.

Comment: An atomic write seems much more important than any ~ms speed considerations.